# Are CAD questions allowed?

Tags: discussion, support, on-topic-definition

That is Computer Aided Design, like Onshape, Solidworks, Autodesk Inventor, etc.

It's for designing graphics and 3D models, but not really sure if it's considered graphic design.

Answer (score 3):

### The theory

If you consult the [Help center](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) and more specifically the section [Asking on topic questions](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), this is what it says (I strongly suggest you read the whole thing tough):

> Graphic Design SE is for questions targeted toward design
>   professionals, students, and enthusiasts. This includes questions
>   about:
>
> - graphic arts theory and history;
> - layout, printing and typography;
> - color and composition;
> - the look & feel aspect of web design;
> - illustration and image manipulation.

You'll notice that it doesn't mention software, at all. That is because the means with which you do graphic design are largely irrelevant. For a simple event poster design you could you an almost infinite number of tools. Yet you can still struggle with composition, colour use, tone, etc, regardless of the chosen tool. Any question about graphic design is on topic.

Pure tech support questions or requests for tutorials will be removed or migrated(also see [What not to ask](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and [this answer](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3317/41100)). There's no problem in mentioning the tool you are using, of course. It can help your answerers give a more to the point and actionable answer.

But ideally, you shouldn't have to mention the tool if your question is about pure graphic design.

---

### In Practice

A lot of questions we get are a bit of a blend between both forms mentioned above. In practice, almost all graphic designers have to deal with software that doesn't always do what we want or that we don't fully understand. That's part of being a graphic designer, and when you run into such a problem, the first person you'd want to ask is another graphic designer because they've maybe, probably seen this issue too. That's a normal reaction.

A lot of people on here are also weary of 3D questions, mainly because we do not have enough 3D experts in our user base to answer these questions properly. And also because these questions tend to lean towards the tech support kind of questions. (NB: there have been a few 3D proposals, but they never made it, [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5022/3d-graphics) you can find the latest one).

---

### My advice

Ask your question and let the community decide. The worst that can happen is that the question gets closed. But as long as you adhere to the rules defined in the Help Center you should be fine. Also, you can always step into [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) if you're unsure. We're much more lenient there, as long as you keep it civil.

Comment: I am also much ore likely to answer an offtopic question in chat

Answer (score 1):

### If it's clearly about graphic design

However, don't expect us to do a lot of work to guide your workflow, just the graphic design aspect of it. It's not that we don't necessarily have expertise; for example. I am a mechancal engineer and I do this kind of stuff all the time. However, I won't answer the question if it's clearly out of scope.

### In reality

These questions get asked, however, in practice all but one such question all have been about things other than design.