# New audience-specific texts for our custom close reasons

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

## Background

With [recent changes to the closing system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346638/255554), we can now tailor the texts for custom close reasons to different audiences:

- One text that informs close flaggers, voters, and reviewers when the close reason should be used.
- One brief text that describes the close reason to everybody seeing the question. (It also gets shown in the two following cases.)
- One text to guide the author of a question with improving it, getting help elsewhere, or similar.
- One text to guide users with the [close privilege](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) how to improve the question or guide the asker.

I think this is great since we do not have to have a single text that works on all occasions anymore and have more room for tailored guidance and being more welcoming.

## What happened

I worked together with the other moderators to make use of this system.
The new close reasons went active just now.
The changes retroactively apply to old questions closed with the respective predecessor close reason.

## Why did you not ask us earlier?

The new texts should not contain any surprises; they reflect existing policy.
Since there is more room and the texts are more targetted, there is little risk of the result being accidentally worse than the status quo.
Also, it is rather difficult to grasp which text goes where without seeing the result in action; I got a few things wrong at first myself.
I therefore only gave a [sneak peek in the Ink Spot](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54179905#54179905) (which received no feedback) and considered it better to have you review the result in place, and suggest changes if necessary.

## This question

I’ll post one answer for each of our custom close reasons containing all the texts.
Please use comments to suggest improvements and similar.
Should any complex issues or disagreements arise, I will create separate questions as needed.

Comment: Looks good! What about the other close reasons. Do they just stay as they are?

Comment: @Wolff: You mean the general ones that are the same on any Stack Exchange site? They have already been somewhat modified.

Answer (score 5):

## Does not fulfill requirements for font-identification, style-identification, or critique

**Close reason:**
This text is shown when selecting a reason while flagging or voting to close:

> #### Does not fulfill requirements for font-identification, style-identification, or critique
>
> This question does not fulfill our requirements for [font-identification questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366), [critique requests](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/682), or [style-identificaton questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2931). It is not straightforward to salvage this question with an edit (e.g., a better title).

**General post notice:**
This text is shown under a closed question to everybody:

> This question is **closed** because it does not fulfill our requirements for [font-identification questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366), [critique requests](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/682), or [style-identificaton questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2931). It is not currently accepting answers.

**Post-owner guidance:**
This text is shown under the general post notice to the author of a question:

> Please have a look at the respective requirements and **edit** your question to provide the missing information so that your question is both answerable and useful to others.

**Privileged-user guidance:**
This text is shown under the general post notice to user with the [close privilege](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions):

> Please help the asker to make their question fulfill the requirements and vote to reopen if they have done so.

Answer (score 3):

## Requires specific file, setup, or trial and error

**Close reason:**
This text is shown when selecting a reason while flagging or voting to close:

> #### Requires specific file, setup, or trial and error
>
> Solving this problem requires one of the following: A specific external file that cannot be embedded into the question; a specific setup, such as a particular version of a software or a particular piece of hardware; access to the computer in question for trial and error. Choose this if you cannot reproduce the problem despite having a reasonably similar setup. Also see [this FAQ](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3579).

**General post notice:**
This text is shown under a closed question to everybody:

> **Closed.** Solving this question requires access to a [specific file, setup](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2807), or [trial and error](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3300). This question is not currently accepting answers.

**Post-owner guidance:**
This text is shown under the general post notice to the author of a question:

> Please **edit** your question to include all information required to answer it. For example: If you are asking about the design of a web site, include screenshots of it; if you have problems with broken files, include the steps required to produce them; in many other situations, consider including additional images. A question should not rely on external files, and your problem should be reproducible. If you cannot add information, your question is probably not suited for this site.

**Privileged-user guidance:**
This text is shown under the general post notice to user with the [close privilege](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions):

> Please guide the user to improve their question if possible. If you can include external images without infringing copyright, do so. If you can reproduce the problem, describe the required steps. Otherwise please guide the asker to a resource that is suited to their problem.

Answer (score 3):

## Not within the expertise of graphic designers

**Close reason:**
This text is shown when selecting a reason while flagging or voting to close:

> #### Not within the expertise of graphic designers
>
> This is a software, hardware, or programming question that is not specific to graphic-design tools. A general computer or programming expert is equally or better equipped to answer this question than an expert on the respective graphic-design tool. Also see [this FAQ](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3579). — You can also use this for questions that are blatantly outside of our scope such as questions on video editing, crafting, etc.

**General post notice:**
This text is shown under a closed question to everybody:

> This question is **closed** because it [does not fall within the expertise of graphic designers](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3300). It is not currently accepting answers.

**Post-owner guidance:**
This text is shown under the general post notice to the author of a question:

> If your question requires general expertise with computers, it may be suitable for [Super User](https://superuser.com/). There are many more sites on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites), which **may** be suitable for your question, such as [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) (for programming), [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/), [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/), or [Arts & Crafts](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/).

**Privileged-user guidance:**
This text is shown under the general post notice to user with the [close privilege](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions):

> If you can, use comments to guide the asker where to best post their question. If there are clear problems with the question (e.g., if it is unclear), try to help them to address these before reposting.